# Arduino POST Method

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

In my aurdino code am trying to send POST method to my server API

`int httpCode = http.POST("{\"id\": \"15\", \"data\": { \"ip\": \"12.457.456.64\" }}");`

in the IP Field "12.457.456.64" above, I need to get my current IP WiFi.localIP().

How do I do it

In postman POST method my parameters are

`{ "id": 15, "data": { "ip": "192.168.0.103" }`
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArduinoJSON library to handle all these json format data.

https://arduinojson.org

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
doc["id"] = 43;
doc["ip"] = WiFi.localIP()
```